# If there is no WinDefender icon in the systray, do I have realtime virus protection?

Tags: windows, windows-10, anti-virus, notification-area, windows-defender

When I run Windows Defender from the start menu, the window that appears says "Real time protection: On". And a WinDefender icon appears in the systray. But this icon was not there before I ran WinDefender.

**Was I protected before I ran WinDefender manually?** How can I be sure?

Comment: Hi, did you check if the 'Windows Defender Service' is running ? If so, you should be protected, even if the icon does not show up in the taskbar.

Comment: When you close the Defender window it disappears again from systray?

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 are you running?  After the Anniversary Update (version 1607) was released in August, the Windows Defender icon was updated to automatically appear in the Notification Area.  The bottom line is that you should still be protected, but you can take steps to ensure that the Windows Defender icon either appears or doesn't... your choice:  [How to Remove the Windows Defender Icon From Your Notification Area](http://www.howtogeek.com/264796/how-to-remove-the-windows-defender-icon-from-your-notification-area/)

Comment: @YisroelTech: No, it doesn't. But I certainly have opened the Defender before today, yet today there was no systray icon for it until I opened it again. So the systray icon apparently disappear under certain conditions. Maybe on a logout or on a reboot.

Comment: @Run5k: "Which version of Windows 10 are you running?" - I don't know how to check. I saw [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13443/windows-which-operating-system), opened Start, typed `About your PC` and nothing showed up.

Comment: If you utilize the Run command (WinKey + R) and type in `winver`, it will tell you which version of Windows 10 you currently have.

Comment: @Run5k: I just installed the Anniversary Update (I think) and am at version 1607. Indeed now there's a Defender icon in the systray that doesn't disappear. So the problem is solved. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it accepted :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, and will-do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Windows 10 are you running? After the Anniversary Update (OS build 14393, version 1607) was released in August, the Windows Defender application was updated so that the icon will automatically appear in the Notification Area. Prior to that, it wouldn't appear unless you had the Windows Defender application window open or you implemented a registry modification.

The bottom line is that you should still be protected, but by default the Windows Defender icon won't appear *constantly* unless your Windows 10 machine has at least the baseline Anniversary Update installed.

Answer (score 2):

> If there is no WinDefender icon in the systray, do I have realtime virus protection?

Yes. Since Windows 8, Windows Defender has been very stingy about displaying its tray icon. In fact, if it was not running, Security and Maintenance would have alerted you.

> How can I be sure?

There are three ways:

1. Provoke Windows Defender to respond. There is a test file called "EICAR test file". All antivirus software are expected to catch this file the way they catch malware.

   To create this file, create a text file in a random folder and rename it "eicar.com". Then, open it in Notepad and insert this string in it:

   ```
   X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*
   ```

   Once you save the file and quit, Windows Defender must react by alerting you that it has discovered a malware.
2. You can check with Security and Maintenance in Control Panel. It would tell you whether your antivirus software is up and running.
3. Open Task Manager, go to the Details tab and look for **MsMpEng.exe**. If it is running, then Windows Defender is running.